# Font size tiny on various elements IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I'm debugging [this website](http://bit.ly/1JBjHrL). For some reason on IE9, the font sizes load normally and then shrink once everything has loaded.

What's causing this and how can it be fixed? I've double checked with the IE9 inspector and the px values seem to be missing from the `body` in the CSS.

Here's what I'm seeing via the IE9 inspector:

[image: Grab from IE9 Inspector]

The CSS should read:

```
body {
    color: #555;
    font-family:  "Avenir LT W01_55 Roman1475520", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.875;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Could you show the CSS of the smaller text?

Comment: Actually, check your browser settings. it maybe reducing the font-size of everything.

Comment: I've reset the browser settings and that hasn't resolved the issue. CSS now included in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently IE9 has built-in `font-size: 100%` for `body` aswell as `html`. Set `font-sizes` for `p` tag.

Comment: ALSO, dont use the rem font value. In IE9 there is only partial support of that property.

Comment: It's strange, it's not happening on a similar site I built: http://bit.ly/1SgsbrH. The font-size is being altered on `<p>` tags, headings and nav `<li>` elements.

Comment: @Squideyes, strange, there are no these in-build `font-sizes` on the other website. Let's just conclude IE is bugged as hell